# Delete html elements with php

Tags: php, html

I was wondering if I had an HTML page, how would I delete an element with php, by the name or id of it. so I could have HTML code like this

```
<div>
    <span id='todelete' name='todelete'>This should be deleted</span>
    <?php
       delete('todelete');
    ?>
</div>
```

or something like that, and the web browser would just show an empty div without the span.
Is that possible, or is it more useful to just use javascript for this.

Basically, what I'm saying is before the page is compiled, can you delete elements from it, based on some conditionals, not after the page has loaded

Comment: You need to use javascript for this

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking, but you can't "delete" HTML with `PHP` ..  You'll need `JavaScript` or `JQuery` to remove it from the `DOM`

Comment: To do it with PHP you'll need an AJAX request.  Look in to [JQuery](http://www.jquery.com) for that.  Then you'll need to create a `click` method for the span that calls the ajax method which posts or gets a PHP page with parameters.

Comment: If you were to use output buffering, then you could adapt the HTML output prior it being sent to the browser. Use phpQuery or QueryPath for implementing your hypothetical delete() function. Though that's quite a longwinded workaround. Better to use a templating system and output logic for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears you are getting confused between [server side](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_scripting) and [client side](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client-side_scripting) scripting languages.

PHP is a server side language meaning that once it has been compiled that's it, it can't be changed dynamically in the users browser.

JavaScript on the other hand is a client side scripting language and can manipulate what is on the page dynamically.

Therefore what you are asking to do is impossible using pure PHP once the page has been rendered.

You can use AJAX technology to call a PHP script from within a page already in a browser using JavaScript. You can then use the PHP script being called by the AJAX request to return something that you can use to update a particular section of your page, but there is no pure PHP way that doesn't involve JavaScript at all to do this.

Answer (score 4):

Just an idea...
 have you thought about PHP XPath Query?

// **CSS** *not important*

```
<style>
    div { border:1px solid rgba(255,0,0,0.5); background:rgba(255,0,0,0.1) }
    span{ border:1px solid rgba(0,255,0,0.5); margin:0px 2px; padding:0 20px; 
    background:rgba(0,255,0,0.5)}
</style>
```

// **PHP** *your HTML, in this example a string.*

```
<?php
$string = '
   <div>
       <span id="keep"> John </span>
       <span id="keep"> Susane </span>
       <span id="todelete"> Tree </span>
       <span id="keep"> Karin </span>
       <span id="keep"> Jack </span>
   </div>
';

echo $string;
```

// **PHP** *start new Class DOMDocument and make the query*

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
@$doc->loadHTML($string);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$found = $xpath->query("//span[contains(@id, 'todelete')]");
```

// more **PHP** *I can't explain this well. **I hope someone else can?**

// But The query found the span that contains attribute id with 'todelete'

// I guess it output it as HTML*

```
$element = $found[0]->ownerDocument->saveXML($found[0]);
/* ##### <span id="todelete"> Tree </span> ##### */
echo '<p>delete:' .  $element . '<p>';
```

//Finally **PHP** *Replace in your string what you found with *nothing**

```
echo str_replace($element, '' , $string);

?>
```

I hope its useful. XPath is very powerful and often forgotten. Give it a try. I hope it's enough for your needs. you can copy all the code above and paste it in a .php document.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use php for removing DOM elements. You need to do it with javascript or jQuery.

With **javascript** it will be so

```
var element = document.getElementById("todelete");
element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
```

And with **jQuery** (after including the library)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#todelete").remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't really use php to delete the html once it has been rendered, but you can use conditions in your php code to selectively render certain sections of html depending on the outcome of tests you perform in php...